# searching a date list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection list which contains the following fields

1. Date1
2. Xvalue
3. Yvalue

I want to seach *within this list against another date list*. For every date in the second list I want to get records starting between this minimum date and the next date is which (30 minutes to the minium date).

```
foreach (var item in selectedDates.Where(x => x.Checked))
{
     // item.minDate is my starting date
     // I want all records between item.minDate and 30 minutes added to it)               
     var t = lf.ReplicateBlocks.FindAll(o=> o.minimumCompletionDate >= item.
}

**UPDATE**

  public class ReplicateBlock
    {
        public int ReplicateId { get; set; }
        public string AssayNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime InitiationDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime InitiationTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime minimumCompletionDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime minimumCompletionTime { get; set; }
        public string correctedCount { get; set; }
        public string moduleName { get; set; }
        public string exception { get; set; }
    }


public class RunLogEntryDatesDisplay
{
    public DateTime runDate { get; set; }
    public String DateRange { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
    public string MinimumReplicateId { get; set; }
}
```

The final output I am looking for is a revised Replicate Block list.  RunLogEntryDatesDisplay is a checkbox list posted from the view. In this list I look at the checked date which is *runDate* and starting from the first selection  I add 30 minutes to it and find all records in *ReplicateBlock List* in between and the edges. I will do the same for every selected date in the checbox list and in the end will have a final/filtered ReplicateBlockLisr based on users selections(checked item).

Comment: Is this LINQ2SQL or LINQ2Objects?

Comment: what is the return type for item? Mouse over `var` and if that is an object, you will not see your intended fields. Do you have an interface encapsulating the required fields?

Comment: Show sample data and a desired output.

Comment: My Apologies, I did not post enough information for the problem. Updating it shortly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could loop through the dates and populate a result list:

```
List<ReplicateBlock> blocks = new List<ReplicateBlock>();    
foreach (var item in selectedDates.Where(x => x.Checked))
{
     var t = lf.ReplicateBlocks.Where(o=> 
                 o.minimumCompletionDate >= item.minDate  &&
                 o.minimumCompletionDate <= item.minDate.AddMinutes(30));

     blocks.AddRange(t);
}
```

You could also do it in one query:

```
var query = from d in selectedDates
            from o in lf.ReplicateBlocks
            where d.Checked &&
                  o.minimumCompletionDate >= d.minDate  &&
                  o.minimumCompletionDate <= d.minDate.AddMinutes(30))
            select o;
```

Comment: hey there, I am sorry, I did not post enough information earlier. Basically I think I should not use var t at all?  I just need to filter existing list based on the where clause. I edited the question within a little bit more detail. Thanks again

Comment: @tammy whats wrong with this solution? Just replace `Date1` with `runDate`

Comment: @lazyberezovsky  Yes it works perfect. I was trying to answer as to what I intended to do with var t.  Thanks guys!!